# proof (rule disjE) for nested disjunction

Tags: isabelle, isar

In Isar-style Isabelle proofs, this works nicely:

```
from `a ∨ b` have foo
proof
  assume a
  show foo sorry
next
  assume b
  show foo sorry
qed
```

The implicit rule called by `proof` here is `rule conjE`. But what should I put there to make it work for more than just one disjunction:

```
from `a ∨ b ∨ c` have foo
proof(?)
  assume a
  show foo sorry
next
  assume b
  show foo sorry
next
  assume c
  show foo sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While writing the question, I had an idea, and it turns out to be what I want:

```
from `a ∨ b ∨ c` have foo
proof(elim disjE)
  assume a
  show foo sorry
next
  assume b
  show foo sorry
next
  assume c
  show foo sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 6):

Another canonical way to do this kind of case analysis is as follows:

```
{ assume a
  have foo sorry }
moreover
{ assume b
  have foo sorry }
moreover
{ assume c
  have foo sorry }
ultimately
have foo using `a ∨ b ∨ c` by blast
```

That is, let an automatic tool "figure out" the details at the end. This works especially well when considering arithmetical cases (with `by arith` as final step).

**Update:** Using the new `consider` statement it can be done as follows:

```
notepad
begin
  fix A B C assume "A ∨ B ∨ C"
  then consider A | B | C by blast
  then have "something"
  proof (cases)
    case 1
    show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case 2
    show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case 3
    show ?thesis sorry
  qed
end
```

Comment: I’ve done that as well. One problem is that it lacks the automatisms of `proof`, e.g. setting up cases, `?thesis` and the like.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: True. It works best when the proof is made more readable by explicitly writing an assumption instead of using `case` anyway (which is mostly true for rather short assumptions).

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: `proof` does not set up `?thesis`, `lemma` (or `have`) does. So you can use `?thesis` in the rule/intro/elim-approach only if you could use it in the moreover-approach.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to do case distinction, it seems you can bend the more general `induct` method to do your bidding. For three cases, this would work like this: Prove a lemma `disjCases3`:

```
lemma disjCases3[consumes 1, case_names 1 2 3]:
  assumes ABC: "A ∨ B ∨ C"
  and AP: "A ⟹ P"
  and BP: "B ⟹ P"
  and CP: "C ⟹ P"
  shows "P"
proof -
  from ABC AP BP CP show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

You can use this lemma as follows:

```
from `a ∨ b ∨ c` have foo
proof(induct rule: disjCases3)
  case 1 thus ?case 
     sorry
next
  case 2 thus ?case 
     sorry
next
  case 3 thus ?case 
     sorry
qed
```

The disadvantage is you need a bunch of lemmas to cover any number of cases, `disjCases2`, `disjCases3`, `disjCases4`, `disjCases5` etc., but otherwise it seems to work nicely.