# proof (intro ..., elim ...) with multiple goals

Tags: isabelle

This is an continuation of the question [proof (rule disjE) for nested disjunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901570)

There we learned that

```
assume "(A ∨ B) ∧ C"
hence "thesis"
proof (elim conjE disjE)
```

is a nice idiom to resolve such conjunctions.

But what if I, before being able to use `elim ...`, need to also apply an introduction rule – say, some induction, or `equalityI`. If i try

```
have "(A ∨ B) ∧ C ⟷ (A' ∨ B') ∧ C'"
proof (rule iffI, elim conjE disjE)
```

then the `elim` only acts on the first goal, the other goal is still noisy with unwanted and easily eliminated operators.

So how do I apply it on all goals introduced by the `rule`?

Comment: For example, is there a method like intro` and `elim` that takes both intro and elim rules?

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicky, but your second example is not proper Isar. First in the assumption you need more parentheses (or use `<-->`). Then `equalityI` is a theorem for set equality, I guess you meant `iffI`. Moreover, if your assumption is an equality I don't see the point of applying an *introduction* rule, wouldn't there rather be need for an elimination rule? I'm just noting all this, because it might be confusing for those to read your question much later.

Comment: That’s what I get for believing I can writer proper Isar without Isabelle. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `intro` and `elim` essentially behave like `rule_tac` and `erule_tac`. So you can use these with explicit goal addressing in square brackets. A `[!]` tells such tactic emulation methods to work on all subgoals. For example:

```
have "(A ∨ B) ∧ C ⟷ (A' ∨ B') ∧ C'"
proof(rule_tac [!] iffI | erule_tac [!] disjE conjE)+
```

Comment: An important difference between `intro`/`elim` and `rule_tac`/`erule_tac` is that the former never instantiate schematic variables.