# Applying elimination rule as many times as possible in Isabelle/Isar

Tags: isabelle, isar

Suppose I have a premise such as `A ∨ B ∨ C`, and want to prove `P`. The natural way to prove it is by proving that `A ⟹ P`, `B ⟹ P` and `C ⟹ P`. However, `disjE` is made for 2 cases, so I have to apply it twice:

```
lemma foo: 
  assumes "A ∨ B ∨ C"
  shows "P"
proof (rule disjE)
  assume "A"
  ...
  then show "P"
next
  assume "B ∨ C"
  then show "P"
  proof (rule disjE)
    assume "B"
    ...
    then show "P"
  next
    assume "C"
    ...
    then show "P"
  qed
qed
```

Now of course, I could prove my own `lemma disjE_3 [rulify]: assumes "P ∨ Q ∨ R" "P ⟹ A" "Q ⟹ A" "R ⟹ A" shows "A"` and use it instead, which would result in a much more readable proof:

```
lemma foo: 
  assumes "A ∨ B ∨ C"
  shows "P"
proof (rule disjE_3)
  assume "A"
  ...
  then show "P"
next
  assume "B"
  ...
  then show "P"
next
  assume "C"
  ...
  then show "P"
qed
```

On the other hand, what if I have 4 cases, or 5, or 10? It seems very inconvenient to create rules for every case you might need. Although you can apply multiple rules at once, `proof (rule disjE disjE)` doesn't seem to cut it in this case.

So, is there a way to reduce the subgoals to a "minimal form" by applying a rule as many times as possible?

Comment: Having looked around, it seems like your question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901570/proof-rule-disje-for-nested-disjunction. I have little to add to what has already been stated in the answers with the exception of that you should look in the manual if you seek further information.